# How to fix this bug: border-image with transform will have lines

Tags: html, css

These are the bug lines
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpDCt.png)

run code snippet, you will see thoes lines.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.a {
  width: 650px;
  height: 350px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border: 60px solid transparent;
  border-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEz5D.png') 60 stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: what about building it using CSS and without border-image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change img base64 data to svg，now it work fine

Answer (score 1):

Adding `translateZ(1px)` fixes this somehow.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.a {
  width: 650px;
  height: 350px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translateZ(1px); /* Chrome, Safari, iOS Safari / iOS WebView, Android */
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1) translateZ(1px); /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1) translateZ(1px); /* Edge, Internet Explorer */
  -o-transform: scale(1.1) translateZ(1px); /* Opera, Opera mini */
  transform: scale(1.1) translateZ(1px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border: 60px solid transparent;
  border-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEz5D.png') 60 stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: run code snippet, the line is still there. I'm use Google browser.

Comment: Try with browser vendor specific css. I have updated my answer with it. Working for me correctly.

Comment: It still doesn't work, the Google version: 100.0.4896.88

Comment: Hmm, I am on exact same chrome version and works for me. I'm clueless now. https://jsfiddle.net/__PR7/4njp2s6y/28/

Comment: It's so strange. On my windows computer(win10), the line is still exists on this page: https://jsfiddle.net/__PR7/4njp2s6y/28/

Comment: Can you also try `backface-visibility: hidden;`. I have updated my answer. Not sure if this will work properly on IE...

Comment: `backface-visibility: hidden;` doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I give up xD

Comment: I'm change img base64 data to svg，now it work fine

Comment: glad to know it is finally working :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove transform:scale (1.1). That should work for you. if you want it to expand use other method.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.a {
  width: 650px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 60px solid transparent;
  border-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEz5D.png') 60 stretch;
  object-fit:cover;
  
}

.a:hover {
  transition: all 1s linear;
  height:400px;
  width: 700px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: I want to do some animation with `transform:scale (1.1)`

Comment: like in what way you want to use it?

Comment: like dialog pop up with scale animation

Comment: well you can increase the height and the width @keyframes if you dont want that weird lines i would suggest or onclick or whatever animation you want.

Comment: @DFB see if the code above works for you now.

Comment: These lines are still there

Comment: check it this if it works for you now.

Comment: I'm change img base64 data to svg，now it work fine

Comment: good thing you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try  changing

```
  border: 60px solid transparent;
```

to

```
  border: 60px ridge transparent;
```

My Chrome version is 100.0.4896.75. And this change works for me .
I Guess maybe there is a bug in border render while setting border-image.
Hope this may help you.

Comment: `border: 60px ridge transparent` doesn't work.  It may have something with the computer.

Comment: if change the html ,put another element in div ,set the img as background , there will no lines . Can you accept that? if so ,I'll post another answer.

Comment: I want to solve the problem based on `border-image`

Comment: Try add       will-change:auto;  ?

Comment: `will-change:auto` is not work

Comment: I'm change img base64 data to svg，now it work fine